# How to hide or disable the address bar on Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, microsoft-edge

My team and I are trying to enable an old application that runs on IE to be compatible with Edge.

The main issue we have is we are required to either: 1- Disable the address bar so the user is unable to copy or modify its parameters or 2- hide it completely so users are not able to access it.

The application was built on Struts 2, Java 1.7 for the backend, and it uses JSP and JavaScript for the front end. We have searched everywhere and we have been unable to find a solution to this issue.

Comment: You cannot hide the address bar, due to security concerns. However, you can use some 'hacks' to keep the user in full screen.

Comment: The back-end technology is completely irrelevant; this is purely a client-side concern. The only way this can be done is via whatever kiosk mode is offered by a given browser. If your goal is some appearance of "security" you're barking up the wrong tree anyway.

Comment: I knew that hidding the bar was kind of out of the question. However, I was hoping to be able to disable it or greyed out so users could see it but not change it.

Answer (score 4):

You said,"**The main issue we have is we are required to either: 1- Disable the address bar so the user is unable to copy or modify its parameters or 2- hide it completely so users are not able to access it.**"

The Edge browser does not support hiding the address bar.

As a workaround, you can try to install that site as an app.

To add the site as an App, go to `Settings and more(ALT + F)-> Apps-> Install this site as an app`.

[image]

Now if you launch the app, it will not display the address bar.

But users can open the site in the Edge browser from the app, so not sure whether this is suitable for you.

If your requirement is that users should not able to modify/ copy the parameters then I suggest you make the [post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) requests instead of [Get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) requests. It may help you to avoid this issue.

Comment: It still shows a bar on top showing the title and address URL :( Even after installing as an app.

Answer (score 1):

When opening edge use `prefix --app="www.google.com"
or

```
 %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe --app="www.google.com"
```

this will hide the address bar

Comment: For me, it works fine. In fact, I tried with CLI by sending the --app argument also through the shortcut, it perfectly hides the address bar. thanks. 

Not sure about down vote